# Creating a promise array for multiple get requests

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, axios

I have a Vue app that at one point calls a sports feeds API end point to get an array of game ID's so I can iterate thru the ID's to get box scores for individual games. So first in in the main app I do:

```
// vue.js
         /* jshint ignore:start */
    axios
      .get(
        `https://api.mysportsfeeds.com/v1.2/pull/nba/${seasonName}/scoreboard.json?fordate=${
          date.yesterday
        }`,
        config
      )
      .then(async response => {
        this.sports_feeds_data = await response.data.scoreboard.gameScore;
        return this.sports_feeds_data;
      })
      .then(async response => {
        // Fill up array with all the game ID's for today's games
        // This will be used to retrieve the Box Scores later
        response.forEach(function(item, index) {
          gameIDs[index] = item.game.ID;
        });

        return gameIDs;
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.sports_feeds_boxscores = getBoxScores(response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.errored = true;
      });
    /* jshint ignore:end */

    console.log("Here are boxScores" + this.sports_feeds_boxscores);================================================================================= //
    // ============================ End Get NBA Scores ================================= //
    // ================================================================================= //
```

Now in getBoxScores.js I want create an array of promises and then fulfill them one at a time via axios.all(promises) into the boxscores array and and return it to Vue.js for further processing. It looks like this:

```
// getBoxScores.js

const axios = require("axios");

let boxScores = [];
let promises = [];

/* jshint ignore:start */
const getBoxScores = gameIDs => {
  console.log(gameIDs);
  gameIDs.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item); // nothing output
    console.log("Im in forEach"); // nothing output
    let myUrl = `https://api.mysportsfeeds.com/v1.2/pull/nba/2018-2019-regular/game_boxscore.json?gameid=${item}`;

    promises.push(
      axios({
        method: "get",
        headers: {
          Authorization:
            "Basic NzAxMzNkMmEtNzVmMi00MjdiLWI5ZDYtOTgyZTFhOnNwb3J0c2ZlZWRzMjAxOA=="
        },
        url: myUrl,
        params: {
          teamstats: "none",
          playerstats: "PTS,AST,REB,3PM",
          sort: "stats.PTS.D",
          limit: 3,
          force: true
        }
      })
    );
  });



    console.log(promises);
  axios.all(promises).then(function(results) {
    results.forEach(function(response) {
      boxScores.push(response.data.gameboxscore);
    });
    return boxScores;
  });
};
/* jshint ignore:end */

module.exports = getBoxScores;
```

Problem: 
  Update: See promises[] ok but this.sports_feeds_boxscores still shows as empty on getBoxScores(response) return. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: *"I then call the function"* : it is important to see all code in *one* script to see exactly what you mean with phrases like this. But please provide the *minimum* code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Code updated per request.

Comment: because ` gameIDs` is fetched asynchronously and you make the call before it is done. The boxScores(gameIDs);` call should be after your loop of setting the `gameIDs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you retrieve data asynchronously, you need to keep going with the asynchronous pattern and not fall back to synchronous sequences.

For example, you access `gameIDs` synchronously right after you *launched* an asynchronous request to get it, so that will not work: when executing `boxScores(gameIDs);` the array `gameIDs` will not yet have been populated.

So your code should be organised like this:

```
axios.get(url, config)
    .then(async response => { .... })
    .then(async response => { 
        .... 
        return gameIDs; // <-- better practice to drive the output through the chain
    })
    .then(boxScores); // <-- call it asynchronously!
    .catch(error => { ... });

// Whatever code comes here should not expect anything from the above 
// asynchronously retrieved data. It will not yet have been retrieved
```

Be careful with `console.log`: it may give the wrong impression that your data is present in the array at the time you made the log. This is not necessarily true: the console retrieves content *later*, at the moment when you expand the array in the console. It does not always reflect the situation *at the time the log was made*.